# missing input file in snakemake

Tags: python, snakemake

below is my snakefile script.

```
import os
import glob
import yaml

##load config file
configfile: "config/config.yaml"

##ref and query locations
referance = config["reference_loc"]
query = config["query_loc"]

##output file location
output = config["output"]   

##sample file name
suffix = [".fsa", ".fasta", ".fa", ".fna", ".fas"]
sample_file = glob.glob(query+"*"+str(suffix))
sample1 = [item.removeprefix(query) for item in sample_file]
sample2 = [item.removesuffix(".fasta") for item in sample1]
sample3 = [item.removesuffix(".fas") for item in sample2]
sample4 = [item.removesuffix(".fsa") for item in sample3]
sample5 = [item.removesuffix(".fna") for item in sample4]
sample = [item.removesuffix(".fa") for item in sample5]

##referance file name
ref_file = glob.glob(referance+"*"+str(suffix))
ref1 = [item.removeprefix(referance) for item in ref_file]
ref2 = [item.removesuffix(".fasta") for item in ref1]
ref3 = [item.removesuffix(".fas") for item in ref2]
ref4 = [item.removesuffix(".fsa") for item in ref3]
ref5 = [item.removesuffix(".fna") for item in ref4]
ref = [item.removesuffix(".fa") for item in ref5]

##rules
rule all:
    input:
        expand(output+"final/{ref}_merged.csv", ref = ref)

rule blast:
    input:
        expand(output+'{sample}_{ref}.txt', sample = sample, ref = ref)
```

related rules are also found below

```
rule blast:
    input:
        query=query+'{sample}'+str(suffix),
        ref=referance+'{ref}'+str(suffix)
    output:
        output+'{sample}_{ref}.txt'
    threads:
        workflow.cores
    conda:
        'envs/blast.yaml'
    shell:
        "blastp -subject {input.ref} -query {input.query} -outfmt '6 qacc sacc pident length qcovs evalue mismatch gaps qseq sseq qlen slen sstart send' -out {output} -num_threads {threads}"
```

```
rule merge_data:
    input:
        rules.blast.output
    output:
        output+"final/{ref}_merged.csv"
    conda:
        'envs/pandas.yaml'
    scripts:
        ../scripts/pd_blastresults.py'
```

i get a return message with the following message,

```
snakemake --cores 14 --use-conda all
Building DAG of jobs...
MissingInputException in line 39 of /home/user/Desktop/newtest/workflow/Snakefile:
Missing input files for rule all:
    affected files:
        /home/user/Desktop/data/results/final/GlpTReferenceNC_000913.3_merged.csv
```

and if i use the other rule i also get a similar message

```
snakemake --cores 14 --use-conda blast
Building DAG of jobs...
MissingInputException in line 43 of /home/user/Desktop/newtest/workflow/Snakefile:
Missing input files for rule blast:
    affected files:
        /home/user/Desktop/data/results/GlpTCP014497.1_GlpTReferenceNC_000913.3.txt
        /home/user/Desktop/data/results/GlpTCP063774.1_GlpTReferenceNC_000913.3.txt
        /home/user/Desktop/data/results/GlpTCP014488_GlpTReferenceNC_000913.3.txt
        /home/user/Desktop/data/results/GlpTCP103710.1_GlpTReferenceNC_000913.3.txt
        /home/user/Desktop/data/results/GlpTCP014522.1_GlpTReferenceNC_000913.3.txt
```

And i have trying so much to figure out what is happening, i don't seem to find the issue. Help is much appreciated. Thank you.

what i tried to do is:

1. specify locations for each files and not through wildcards, and make the script work on each alone, also got the same errors.
2. kept sample wildcards and only specified ref location, still same issue
3. re-wrote the whole snakefile, same error.

i did not uninstall snakemake or conda yet, i want to find a solution before i try this way.

Edited after euronion answer,

that helped me figure out the issue. i added all the rules to the main sankefile and found out what was happening there.

```
    import os
    import sys
    import glob
    import yaml
    import pandas as pd
    
    ##load config file
    configfile: "config/config.yaml"
    
    ##ref and query locations
    referance = config["reference_loc"]
    query = config["query_loc"]
    
    ##output file location
    output = config["output"]   
    
    ##sample file name
    suffix = [".fsa", ".fasta", ".fa", ".fna", ".fas"]
    sample_file = glob.glob(query+"*"+str(suffix))
    sample1 = [item.removeprefix(query) for item in sample_file]
    sample2 = [item.removesuffix(".fasta") for item in sample1]
    sample = [item.removesuffix(".fa") for item in sample2]
    print(sample)
    
    ##rules
    rule all:
        input:
            expand(output+"final/{sample}_merged.csv", sample = sample)
    
    rule blast:
        input:
            query=query+'{sample}.fasta',
            ref=referance
        output:
            output+'{sample}.txt'
        threads:
            workflow.cores
        conda:
            'envs/blast.yaml'
        shell:
            "blastp -subject {input.ref} -query {input.query} -outfmt '6 qacc sacc pident length qcovs evalue mismatch gaps qseq sseq qlen slen sstart send' -out {output} -num_threads {threads}"
    
    rule merge_data:
        input:
            rules.blast.output
        output:
            output1=output+"final/{sample}_merged.csv"
        conda:
            'envs/pandas.yaml'
        script:
            "../scripts/pd_blastresults.py"
```

but now i got into another issue is specifying my different reference files, i'll just figure that later.

Comment: The way your example is set up cannot work (You have two rules `blast` with the same name, the second `rule blast` has a missing `,` in the input list and from the way your rules are setup snakemake cannot determine the wildcards for `rules.blast.output`.
I suggest you reduce your example to the bare minimum (remove list processing, `expands`, `config` calls) to track down the problem. If you still cannot find it, please include a working, ideally a *MWE* (Minimum Working Example) in your post

Comment: Thank you, that helped. the issue was mostly related to {ref}

Comment: what was it? i am having the same issue, so if you could manage post an answer the question it would be great